# Cannot display JSON value with Array(

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Hello** I found a problem displaying url value.

 Is the problem in **" Array ( "** ?

```
Array ( [ {
    "playabilityStatus": {
        "status": "OK", "playableInEmbed": true, "contextParams": "Q0FFU0FnZ0M] => "
    }
    , "streamingData": {
        "expiresInSeconds":"21540", "formats":[ {
            "itag": 18, "url": "http://example.com/360.mp4", "mimeType": "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2\"", "bitrate": 198298, "width": 638, "height": 360, "lastModified": "1567026236090610", "contentLength": "20775840", "quality": "medium", "qualityLabel": "360p", "projectionType": "RECTANGULAR", "averageBitrate": 198286, "audioQuality": "AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW", "approxDurationMs": "838217", "audioSampleRate": "44100", "audioChannels": 1
        }
        , {
            "itag": 22, "url": "http://example.com/360x1.mp4", "mimeType": "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2\"", "bitrate": 404000, "width": 1276, "height": 720, "lastModified": "1567026270240429", "quality": "hd720", "qualityLabel": "720p", "projectionType": "RECTANGULAR", "audioQuality": "AUDIO_QUALITY_MEDIUM", "approxDurationMs": "838217", "audioSampleRate": "44100", "audioChannels": 1
        }
        , {
            "itag": 43, "url": "http://example.com/360x2.mp4", "mimeType": "video/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\"", "bitrate": 2147483647, "width": 640, "height": 360, "lastModified": "1567026831970178", "contentLength": "19705302", "quality": "medium", "qualityLabel": "360p", "projectionType": "RECTANGULAR", "audioQuality": "AUDIO_QUALITY_MEDIUM"
        }
        ], "adaptiveFormats":[ 
        ...
```

$arr is = php file ytb-dl.php

```
$json_output = json_decode($arr);
foreach ($json_output['streamingData'] as $formats) {
    echo $formats['url'];    
}
```

Comment: That file isn't JSON, it looks more like the output of `var_export()`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is `Array (`

Comment: What's going on? Everything before the first `{` just disappeared from that URL.

Comment: Thanks very much, i forget the array "  , $arr)  " in ytb-dl.php

Answer (score 0):

Be aware which structure of data you are using, try code below, is working for me.
Please check if link `https://webstickers.000webhostapp.com/ytb-dl.php` is active.

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://webstickers.000webhostapp.com/ytb-dl.php');

$json_output = json_decode($content, true);

foreach ($json_output['streamingData'] as $formats) {
if (!is_array($formats)) {
    continue;
}
foreach ($formats as $format) {
    echo $format['url'] . PHP_EOL;
}
}
```